# Why does LOVE freeze when I try to run my code?

Tags: lua

I'm very new to Lua and have no clue what's going on. I've looked at the official documentation for LOVE (the thing I'm using to run Lua) and I don't see an issue with my code. I've tried a couple things, none of which have worked. When I run the code, the LOVE screen just freezes and then I have to close it.

Here is the code:

```
while lives ~= 0 do
    function love.keypressed(key, scancode)
        if love == "a" then
            score = score + 5
        end
        if scancode == "w" then
            print(score)
        end
        if scancode == "s" then
            lives = lives - 1
        end
        if scancode == "d" then
            score = score + 10
        end
        if scancode == "l" then
            print(lives)
        end
    end  
end
```

When I run this through LOVE, it creates two windows, a console window and a blank white window that after a couple seconds it says "Not Responding" and then I have to close it.

Edit: I've tried to type in both windows

Comment: You have a loop with no body followed by a function definition

Comment: Sorry, I didn't format the text on the website to show up how it should.

Comment: your while loop defines a function and then on the next run defines the same function, `lives` will never change value. You are running an infinite loop that simply defines the same function and never gives the rest of your code a chance to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to put it into the while loop, remove the while loop and try it like that.

Comment: I just tried that, I get the same error.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with LOVE, I think you do not need to put it into the while loop, that might be causing your issues, remove the while loop and try it like that.

Comment: No problem, if you could mark the answer as the solution that would be great